# Migration From Windows authentication with AD (Active Directory) to Form authentication using okta integration. Getting 302 on request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

My project was running on Windows authentication with AD, now client asked me to convert authentication from Windows to okta. I have made the changes using form authentication to manage signin and signout.

Everything was working fine in development, but once it went to QA, some URL creating problems.

I had okta/login which return a view with a button (say login with okta), once button is clicked it redirect to okta/authorize which will open the OKTA login page.

Problem is I am getting http 302 in okta/authorize.

[image]

The okta/authorize goes to login with return url.

Can anybody help me with this?